# Can we send image as a string parameter in webserrvices in android

Tags: android

I need to send image as a string parameter in `webservices` to server. Just like we send string parameter in `webservices`. For this I am converting image into string as follows

```
Resources r = this.getResources();

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.icon);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(image,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now I need to send this string `encodedImage` like this.

```
calling  Url-- http://pdtrptr/asfsdf/services/add.php?file=encodedImage
```

My question is how can we send this string image along with url --like above url

Is server coding for receiving string image differs for android compare to iphone because (after sending the image from android to server, when trying to get from server i am getting null value), where as iphone mobile is able to send and receive the image.

Thanks

Comment: For Image Uploading you need to use HTTP Post method.

Comment: yes i am using Http Post method to call webservices.Is there anything else to do about sending string image beside my above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try the code which is providing in following link...

[Image Upload with HttpPost](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)